# Does "for the past days" need to be "for the past *few* days"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Does it sound natural to a native speaker to say "for the past days" without using the word "few"?:

> For the past days [note here the omission of "few" in "past ***few*** days"], I have been unable to concentrate on anything.

Or should "for the past days" always be used as "past few days"? My worry is that I don't want to talk about the past "few" days (e.g. 3 days), but maybe the last 6-10 days or so. Yet autocorrect tools are telling me I should include "few" and the vast majority of instances I found used "for the past *few* days" (related: https://www.italki.com/en/post/question-361068 ).

Comment: You could side-step the problem by saying "I have been unable to concentrate on anything recently."

Comment: @WeatherVane good idea! But I'm also interested in the question. I'm not a native speaker and, to me, it makes sense to omit "few", but it might be the case that it's not idiomatic after all (the link I posted seems to go in this direction)

Comment: It doesn't sound natural to say "for the past days", it seems as if a quantifier is missing. But "for the past week" would seem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I can't think of any scenario where "for the past days" would be used by native speakers.

> My worry is that I don't want to talk about the past "few" days (e.g. 3 days), but maybe the last 6-10 days or so.

You could say

- for the past several days
- in recent days
- for the past week or two
- recently
- since the start of the month (or whatever time marker applies)

etc.